# Unsafe pointer manipulation

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, unsafe, fixed-point

I'm trying to write a CPU emulator in C#. The machine's object looks like this:

```
class Machine 
{
    short a,b,c,d; //these are registers.

    short[] ram=new short[0x10000];  //RAM organised as 65536 16-bit words

    public void tick() { ... } //one instruction is processed
}
```

When I execute an instruction, I have a switch statement which decides what the result of the instruction will be stored in (either a register or a word of RAM)

I want to be able to do this:

```
short* resultContainer;

if (destination == register)
{
    switch (resultSymbol) //this is really an opcode, made a char for clarity
    {
       case 'a': resultContainer=&a;
       case 'b': resultContainer=&b;
       //etc
    }
}
else
{
    //must be a place in RAM
    resultContainer = &RAM[location];
}
```

then, when I've performed the instruction, I can simply store the result like:

```
*resultContainer = result;
```

I've been trying to figure out how to do this without upsetting C#.

How do I accomplish this using `unsafe{}` and `fixed(){ }` and perhaps other things I'm not aware of?

Comment: `bregister`? Did you mean `resultContainer`?

Comment: Cool, DCPU / 0x10c :)

Comment: yep :) Is DCPU the only architecture with non-weird register names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would implement it:

```
class Machine
{
    short a, b, c, d;
    short[] ram = new short[0x10000];

    enum AddressType
    {
        Register,
        DirectMemory,
    }

    // Gives the address for an operand or for the result.
    // `addressType`and `addrCode` are extracted from instruction opcode
    // `regPointers` and `ramPointer` are fixed pointers to registers and RAM.
    private unsafe short* GetAddress(AddressType addressType, short addrCode, short*[] regPointers, short* ramPointer)
    {
        switch (addressType)
        {
            case AddressType.Register:
                return regPointers[addrCode]; //just an example implementation
            case AddressType.DirectMemory:
                return ramPointer + addrCode; //just an example implementation
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public unsafe void tick()
    {
        fixed (short* ap = &a, bp = &b, cp = &c, dp = &d, ramPointer = ram)
        {
            short*[] regPointers = new short*[] { ap, bp, cp, dp };

            short* pOperand1, pOperand2, pResult;
            AddressType operand1AddrType, operand2AddrType, resultAddrType;
            short operand1AddrCode, operand2AddrCode, resultAddrCode;

            // ... decipher the instruction and extract the address types and codes

            pOperand1 = GetAddress(operand1AddrType, operand1AddrCode, regPointers, ramPointer);
            pOperand2 = GetAddress(operand2AddrType, operand2AddrCode, regPointers, ramPointer);
            pResult = GetAddress(resultAddrType, resultAddrCode, regPointers, ramPointer);

            // execute the instruction, using `*pOperand1` and `*pOperand2`, storing the result in `*pResult`.

        }
    }
}
```

To get the address of the registers and RAM array, you have to use the `fixed` statement. Also you can only use the acquired pointers in the `fixed` block. So you have to pass around the pointers.

Comment: this seems like the best way, but it's still so ugly :(

Answer (score 1):

What if we look at the problem from another view? Execute the instruction and store the result in a variable (`result`), and then decide on where you should put the result. Doesn't work?

Comment: that is a good idea, but I don't think it'll work too well, because most instructions are like: ````add a,b````, so I have to put ````a```` and ````b```` into a variable, add them, and put the result into ````a````. I need to be able to access ````a```` before computing

Answer (score 0):

A good option, one I had planned for DevKit but not yet implemented, is to generate your emulation code.  It's a time-honoured, tried and tested solution.  For every opcode/register combination, or some efficient subset, generate the code for ADD A,B and SUB X,Y separately.  You can use a bitmask to grab the specific case you're looking for and simply execute the correct code.  Compiler should be able to use a jump table under the hood, and there's no lookups, no conditionals, should be pretty efficient.